# How to re-enable auto-login for Safari that is removed after new update?

Tags: safari

I had this feature after updating to Safari, which automatically logs in to websites with the autofill (so I don't have to click Log in or Submit buttons or press enter).

However, this option was somehow removed after the 13.0.2 update to Safari.

Is there a way to re-enable this functionality?

Comment: That behaviour used to be default many years ago. It made a brief return in the past 6 months or so, but I'd bet people considered it a bug & it was removed again, unfortunately. I liked it too.

Comment: It was a design flaw. Most people read and do actions from top to bottom, so they'd press the autofill button, then click other options such as captchas or "keep me logged in" buttons. I'm glad it's gone, because I kept doing that, going from top to bottom and getting login errors because it'd click log in before I was able to complete the captcha.